# Return an extra column based on the results of a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have two tables, one with `deals` and one with `companies`.

In the table with companies I have lat's and lng's. With a subquery I am able to get the deals, the companies and the distances between the deals and one specific location. But I want a column with the 3 deal id's that are the closest to that location.

**10.4.6-MariaDB**

I use:

```
SELECT 
  deals.*, 
  (
    6371 * acos(
      cos(radians(51.957478)) *  
      cos(radians(companies.lat )) *  
      cos(radians(companies.lng ) -  radians(4.493695)) +
      sin(radians(51.95747)) *  
      sin(radians(companies.lat))
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM `deals`
LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `deals`.cid = `companies`.id
```

This gives:

```
id:  cid:    distance:
15   125      1.25152
etc.
```

I want:

```
id:    cid:    distance:    closest_companies:
15     125      1.25152     126, 127, 128, 129 <- these are cid's (just an example)
```

Comment: Under  "I want:" the column with closest_companies is the expected data.

Comment: So given a specific company (`deals.cid`), you want to calculate the three companies that are closest to it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want get all the deals, the company that has the deal and also the three closest companies. I use this for a productfeed for marketing.

Comment: @TimodeVent How many rows are there in your `companies` table ? Based on your requirements, you are looking at `CROSS JOIN`, as you will need to check each company against all the other companies, and find the distances between them to get the closest 3. This could be very inefficient for large tables. So, another way could be to store the distances in a separate table and use them directly. This process can be done via a cronjob during off-peak hours.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya In the table with deals 3800 and in the table with companies 11000 . The query I use only resultst in about 320 deals (that are the active ones) and they change very frequently. 

I hope it's possible to create the colmn without creating a new table.

Comment: @TimodeVent what is your MySQL Server version ? To get that, run `SELECT Version();` query and edit the question to add the Server details.

Comment: 10.4.6-MariaDB, I have added it to the question